# find the CSS path (ancestor tags) in HTML using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get all the ancestor div tags where I match a text. So for example if the html looks like [HTML snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aePNZ.png)

And i'm searching for "Earl E. Byrd". I wanna get a list which contains {"buyer-info","buyer-name"}

This is what i did

```
r=requests.get(self.url,verify='/path/to/certfile')
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
                divTags = soup.find_all('div')
```

How should I proceed ?

Comment: Paste as text, not as img and in your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for the div by text and get all the previous divs that have *title* attributes, first find the div using the text, then use  `find_all_previous` setting `title=True`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
div = soup.find('div', text="Earl E. Byrd")

print([div["title"]] + [d["title"] for d in div.find_all_previous("div", title=True)])
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using an [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression :

```
//div[@title="buyer-info"]/div[text() = "Carlson Busses"]/ancestor::div
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I do not want to write "buyer-code" in the script. I can code in "Carlson Busses"  and Based on this text I want to get the title in that div ( buyer-name)  as well as all the titles in the parent divs.( if it has parent tags in the hierarchy).